# How to show logarithmic growth is slower than polynomial growth?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha  \ > 0 $  be fixed. How to show that $x^\alpha > \ln x   $     for sufficiently large $x$? I have done for the case $\alpha  \ >1$ but stuck for $\alpha  \ < 1$.

Can  any one give some hint?

Comment: Actually, what you've called exponential growth is polynomial growth; exponential growth is even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Doubling $x$ increases $\ln x$ by $\ln 2$, which for sufficiently large $\ln X>0$ multiplies the logarithm by less than $2^{\alpha/2}$. This $x^{\alpha}/\ln x$ multiplies by more than  $2^{\alpha/2} > 1$. Doubling $x$ repeatedly can therefore make the ratio arbitrarily large.

Comment: i simply not getting you...can u please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*  L'Hôpital's rule.  It's applicable as numerator and denominator go to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=u^{1/a}$. Then $x^a\gt\ln x$ for sufficiently large $x$ if and only if $u\gt{1\over a}\ln u$ for sufficiently large $u$. No matter how small $a$ is (as long as it's positive), $f'(u)={d\over du}(u-{1\over a}\ln u)=1-{1\over au}\to1$ as $u\to\infty$, and this in turn implies $f(u)=u-{1\over a}\ln u\to\infty$ as $u\to\infty$, so in particular $f(u)\gt0$ for sufficiently large $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^a\ln(x)$ for $a\in]0,1[$.

We have $f'(x)=\dfrac{a\ln(x)+1}{x^{1-a}}\to-\infty\quad$ the limit is not hard  to determine since the numerator goes to minus infinity and the denominator to positive zero.

By continuity, we can conclude that $f\searrow$ in a neighborhood of $0^+$.

Since $\ln(x)<0$ near $0^+$ and $x^a>0$ then $f(x)\le 0$ near $0^+$.

These two conditions show that $|f(x)|<C$ for $x\ll 1$.

Now $|f(x)|=|x^a\ln(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x})|=|(\sqrt{x})^a(\sqrt{x})^a2\ln(\sqrt{x})|=|2(\sqrt{x})^af(\sqrt{x})|<2C\,|x|^{\frac a2}\to 0$